# How to update anaconda python distribution to python3 without reinstalling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

How can I update my root anaconda python installation without reinstalling Anaconda from scratch? I don't want to reinstall from scratch because I want to keep the many virtual environments I've created.

Comment: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/python-3-support-anaconda

Answer (score 0):

You can do either

```
conda update python
conda install python={version}
```

For example,

```
conda install python=3.5
```

### Reference

1. [Managing Python](https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html)